# How do you multiply every element inside a 2D array by -1?

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d, multiplication

I have a 2D array filled with values. To multiply every element inside a 1D array, you can use list comprehensions. Yet I'm uncertain how to formulate the list comprehension to work over a 2D array.

```
R = [[0, 0.94, 0.91, 0.96, 0.93, 0.92],
    [0.94, 0, 0.94, 0.97, 0.91, 0.92],
    [0.91, 0.94, 0, 0.94, 0.90, 0.94],
    [0.96, 0.97, 0.94, 0, 0.93, 0.96],
    [0.93, 0.91, 0.90, 0.93, 0, 0.91],
    [0.92, 0.92, 0.94, 0.96, 0.91, 0]]

RNeg = [[i*(-1) for i in R]]
```

How do I fix RNeg to perform the correct operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numpy.array(R) * -1
```

is the easiest

if you have to do it by hand

`[[val*-1 for val in row] for row in R]`